# Read-line Not Returning a String (in Common Lisp)?

Tags: file-io, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm having difficulty understanding how to use `read-line` to return a simple string from a text file. Say file.txt consists of two lines like:

```
abc
defg
```

Then in SBCL 2.3.0:

```
(with-open-file (stream "file.txt") (read-line stream nil)) =>
"abc
NIL
```

I was expecting the result to be the string "abc" with the newline discarded.

Comment: Looks like there is " character missing in the output after abc? Why is that?

Comment: Does this maybe have something to do with the different way Windows & Unix end lines? Unix ends with line-feed, but Windows ends with carriage-return,line-feed. Thus `readline` returns different results in Windows?

Comment: that's possible. IIRC sbcl is not respecting the Windows newline standard on a Windows machine.

Comment: On my Windows 10 machine, SBCL 2.3.2, it returns :
"abc"
NIL

Comment: The problem may come from your configuration, try to run your code using a specific sbcl invocation: sbcl --no-sysinit --no-userinit --eval "(with-open-file (stream "file.txt") (read-line stream nil))"

Comment: @JérômeRadix Strange. On my Windows 11 machine after starting sbcl with your no-sysinit and no-userinit, I still get the extra CR in the result. (Running your eval code at startup produces an error, but this is a fresh sbcl download??) I still think it has more to do with the Windows standard of ending a line with CRLF. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the documentation for both [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm) and [`read-line`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_rd_lin.htm).

`with-open-file` returns *results*, where *results---the values returned by the forms.*.

`read-line` returns two [values](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_values.htm): *line, missing-newline-p*.

In your example, *line* has value `"abc"` and *missing-newline-p* has value `NIL`.

Comment: This must be something obvious, but I still don't get it. The first value returned by `read-line` does not seem like a typical string in my example??? However, `(uiop:read-file-lines "file.txt")` works as expected.